# SQL Server Management Studio installation fails with Invalid location

Tags: ssms

I am trying to re-install SSMS after my previous installation went corrupt due to one of my corrupt hard drives (E: in the image below). Trying to uninstall the previous version does not work as it tries to find the uninstaller from that drive.

Running the installer anyways gives me the following error with an un-editable location to point to a valid drive.

"Invalid location. Please enter a valid location to proceed."

[image]

I ma pretty sure that the remnants of the older installation must be in the registry somewhere. Any idea where to look for ? Or any alternate solution to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you need to remove the following registry key and that gets the new setup going.

For x64 OS :

**"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"**

For x86 OS :

**"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"**

Then try installing after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and neither of the above reg keys existed.

To get past this I had to use Shift + Right click and select "Run as a different user". This allowed me to enter the appropriate admin credentials and continue with the install.

Answer (score 0):

First, you start with RUN then type regedit and follow that "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" and delete it, it will work
[RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd4H0.png)